# Understanding the basis and orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the textbook "Elementary Linear Algebra" by Howard Anton and I've been trying to understand the difference between these two examples that are given in the textbook:
[Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Ci6.png)
[Example 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu4oe.png)

(Sorry, you'll have to click the link to view the two examples).

So in example 3, it states "find a basis for the solution space of the homogeneous system", and it comes up with {(-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (-4, 0, -2, 1, 0, 0), (-2, 0, 0, 1, 0)} which I believe they solve using Gaussian. Then in example 6 to find the basis for an orthogonal complement, it takes those same 4 vectors in R^6 from example 3, and then ends up with exactly the same solution {(-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (-4, 0, -2, 1, 0, 0), (-2, 0, 0, 1, 0)} as the basis for the orthogonal complement of W.

How can the basis for those vectors be the same as the basis for the orthogonal complement? I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You have a homogeneous system of linear equations. Hence, any solution will be orthogonal to the vectors given in example 6 as its the same system of linear equations. The row space of a matrix is orthogonal to the null space of the matrix

Comment: On terminology: "orthogonal basis" has a different meaning than "basis of the orthogonal complement". An orthogonal basis is a basis in which all of the basis elements are perpendicular to each other. The "orthogonal complement" of a subspace is the collection of all vectors that are perpendicular to every vector in the subspace. This collection is itself another subspace. A basis for the orthogonal complement is just that - any linearly independent set of vectors that spans the orthogonal complement. The elements of this basis do not be need to be orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If we are given, as in example 6, a set of vectors $\{\mathbf w_i\}_{i=1}^n$ in $\Bbb R^m$, and define $W = \text{span}(\mathbf w_1, \dots \mathbf w_n)$. Then the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ of $W$ is the set of all vectors perpendicular to every vector of $W$. To determine if $\mathbf x \in W^\perp$, it is sufficient to check if it is perpendicular to every element of the spanning set $\{\mathbf w_i\}_{i=1}^n$. That is, to check if $\mathbf x$ is a solution to the system of equations $$\mathbf w_1\cdot \mathbf x = 0\\\vdots\\\mathbf w_1\cdot \mathbf x = 0$$

That is, the problem of finding the orthogonal complement of $W$ is the problem of solving a certain system of homogenous linear equations. For example 6, the system of linear equations to be solved is exactly the system in example 3. Thus the solution of example 3 and of example 6 are the same, as the two examples are two different ways of expressing what is the same root problem.